# git log --author not showing all commits

Tags: git, version-control

I've made dozen of commits but when I do a `git log --author=pauld` I'm only seeing the last three. Without the author filter the full history is shown. I've tried variations with `--full-history` and a few other options but nothing seems to work. For some reference, I need to list of commits by an author since I given date so that they can be cherry picked. This is just a strange road block early on I didn't expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To verify each commit's "author" field is as expected (spelling, characters, etc.), a quick audit of the commit ref, message, and author/committer would be good check.

`git log --format=raw`

Alternatively, it may be the commits have a `committer` with the username "pauld" if these commits have been rebased or previously cherry-picked, rather than the original "author" field.

`git log --committer="pauld"`

Even more broadly, you can use string value for the option `--committer` or `--author` as a regular expression should there be some spelling disparity.

`git log --author="pau*"`

Answer (score 13):

Use **-i** argument for case-insensitive search

```
git log -i --author=pauld
```

Answer (score 2):

The `--author` flag uses regular expressions, and what you're passing is case-sensitive: `pauld`. Do all of your log messages contain the exact string `pauld` in the author field?

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the considerations regarding the `--author` option mentioned in other answers already: Are the commits you are missing ancestors of your current HEAD? git log shows only what is reachable from your current HEAD. Use `git log --all` to show commits from all branches.